# Should I take Polearm Gamble or Repel Charge at level 11?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, feats, optimization

I'm in a 4E dnd game, built from lvl1, and we're lvl6 now. My build is a fighter/ranger polearm fighter, kind of a striker/defender build, combining the whole polearm proning with high damage attacks, using either when needed.

Anyway, I was looking at Polearm Gamble at lvl11, and wondering what to take next. I saw Repel charge, and I was curious if having Polearm Gamble negated the need for Repel Charge. There's a million articles on forced movement and Polearm Gamble, but nothing about Repel Charge.

If anyone is interested in my build, I think it will work pretty well and I've tried to make it different enough to not be cookie cutter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Stick with Polearm Gamble**

If you have any kind of forced movement on your OA (and especially if it can trigger `Polearm Momentum`), then `Polearm Gamble` is almost strictly better than Repel Charge. `Polearm Gamble` works when an enemy enters an adjacent square for *any* reason (except forced movement, and possibly shifts as described in the comments below), while `Repel Charge` only works if they charge *you*; not the guy next to you, not someone beyond you, only you.

The sole advantage of `Repel Charge` is that it doesn't make you grant combat advantage to the enemy, but if your opportunity attack can either push 1 or push 2+ and knock prone (with `Polearm Momentum`), then you don't care about granting combat advantage because they won't be able to attack you.

Comment: I've seen a [reference](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Polearm_Gamble) to Polearm Gamble being errated to not affect shifts. Damned if I can find what they were actually talking about in that [errata document](http://wizards.com/dnd/files/UpdateDec2009.pdf) though.

Comment: It's the part of the errata document that talks about shifting, lower left of page 3. I'd say it's up to the DM whether that applies to `Polearm Gamble`, though; it just says shifting doesn't provoke OAs, and `Polearm Gamble` doesn't say enemies *provoke* an OA when they move next to you, it says you can *make* an OA against them when they move adjacent to you. A rules lawyer would say that since `Polearm Gamble` says nothing about *provoking* OAs that shifts not provoking OAs doesn't exempt them from `Polearm Gamble` attacks. Take it to a new question if you disagree with that interpretation.

Comment: I would agree with that wording, since a power or feat bending the rules for specific instances is the basic concept behind their power.

Thanks for the replies, much appreciated.